# Fake BUSD transcation sent from my wallet (not fake 0 token scam)!

Tags: security, bsc, scam, hack, user-safety

Transaction Hash: 0x7800fb4d9345fc7e8b2794a479f414948eb1a9126e14daff11d1802440996a68

The hackers sent fake busd token (with >0 amount) from multiple victims wallet to another wallet without any token approval. This is not the same as fake 0 token transaction. This time it has >0 token amount. If the hackers do not have victims' private key,  How does it possible??

Answer (score 1):

The tokens aren't from the official BUSD contract, but another token with the same name.